# Не стартует вагрант

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox, vagrant

Свежеустановленные вагрант и виртуалбокс. Пытаюсь поднять виртуалку `vagrant up` (пробовал с разными - от бокса не зависит) и все виснет. Ничего не пишет и не завершается. Со флагом `--debug` выводит в конце ошибку "Command not in installer, restoring original environment...". Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: тут советуют прибить повершелл, а в комментах позднее обновить его https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/7823

Comment: @Lexx918 читал уже. Прибить то прибил - ничего не изменилось. А вот как его обновлять я без понятия. Кажется повершелл ведь обновляется вместе с виндой?

Comment: в конце обсуждения есть ссылка на описание процесса установки и обновления, вот эта https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/installing-powershell-5-1wmf-5-1/

Comment: @Lexx918 Спасибо помогло! После обновления повершелла вагрант начал запускаться!